# Generic publisher class

Tags: java

The code below is a publisher base class. I've never really liked the way I implemented this class. Are there any improvements/simplifications I can make to it?

Background:
The execute(...) method is called periodically from ServiceImpl.
ServiceImpl is just a generic service class.

```
package me.munyengm.core.publish;

import static akka.dispatch.Futures.future;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import akka.actor.TypedActor;

import com.google.common.collect.FluentIterable;
import com.loudsight.utilities.Cast;
import com.loudsight.utilities.service.ServiceImpl;
import com.loudsight.utilities.service.core.subscribe.Subscriber;

public abstract class PublisherImpl<T> extends ServiceImpl implements Publisher<T> {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PublisherImpl.class);

    protected static class SubscriberInfoImpl<T> implements Subscription<T> {
        private static final AtomicLong nextId = new AtomicLong();
        private final Subscriber subscriber;
        private final long subscriberId;
        private final T subscriptionData;
        private long updateInterval;
        private long lastRefresh;

        SubscriberInfoImpl(Subscriber subscriber, T subscriptionData, long updateInterval, long lastRefresh) {
            this.subscriber = subscriber;
            this.subscriberId = nextId.incrementAndGet();
            this.subscriptionData = subscriptionData;
            this.updateInterval = updateInterval;
            this.lastRefresh = lastRefresh;
        }

        @Override public long refreshInterval() { return updateInterval; }
        @Override public void setRefreshInterval(long updateInterval) { this.updateInterval = updateInterval; }
        @Override public long getSubscriberId() { return subscriberId;}
        @Override public T getSubscriptionData() { return subscriptionData; }
        @Override public Subscriber getSubscriber() { return subscriber; }
        @Override public long getLastRefresh() { return lastRefresh; }
        @Override public void setLastRefresh(long lastRefresh) { this.lastRefresh = lastRefresh; }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if ((obj != null) && (obj instanceof Subscription)) {
                Subscription<T> info = Cast.uncheckedCast(obj);

                return getSubscriberId() == info.getSubscriberId();
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Long.valueOf(getSubscriberId()).hashCode();
        }
    }

    Comparator<Subscription<T>> c = (o1, o2) -> {
        if (o2.getSubscriberId() != o1.getSubscriberId()) {
            long timeToWait1 = calculateTimeToWait(o1);
            long timeToWait2 = calculateTimeToWait(o2);

            return Long.compare(timeToWait1, timeToWait2);
        }
        return 0;
    };

    private final Map<Long, Subscription<T>> subscriptionMap = new HashMap<>();
    private final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    protected PublisherImpl() {
    }

    @Override public void onSubscribe(Subscription<T> subscription) { }

    @Override public void onUnsubscribe(final long subscriptionId) { }

    @Override
    public final long subscribe(final Subscriber subscriber, final T eventItem, final long updateInterval) {

        Subscription<T> subscription = new SubscriberInfoImpl<>(subscriber, eventItem, updateInterval, 0);
        Publisher<T> this_ = TypedActor.self();
        subscriptionMap.put(subscription.getSubscriberId(), subscription);
        asynchronouslyExecute(() -> {
            this_.onSubscribe(subscription);
            return null;
        });

        return subscription.getSubscriberId();
    }

    @Override
    public void resubscribe(long subscriptionId, long updateInterval) {
        Subscription<T> subscription = getSubscriberBySubscriptionId(subscriptionId);
        subscription.setRefreshInterval(updateInterval);
    }

    protected Subscription<T> getSubscriberBySubscriptionId(final long subscriptionId) {
        return subscriptionMap.get(subscriptionId);
    }

    @Override
    public final void unsubscribe(final long subscriptionId) {
        onUnsubscribe(subscriptionId);
        subscriptionMap.remove(subscriptionId);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Subscription<T>> getSubscribers() {
        return FluentIterable.from(subscriptionMap.values()).toList();
    }

    @Override
    public
    long calculateTimeToWait(Subscription<T> info) {
        long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long nextExecutionTime = info.getLastRefresh() + info.refreshInterval();

        return Math.abs(currentTimeMillis - nextExecutionTime) * (nextExecutionTime / currentTimeMillis);
    }

    @Override
    public long getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean execute() throws  Throwable {

        try {
            List<Subscription<T>> readySubscriptions = FluentIterable.from(getSubscribers())
                    .filter(s -> (calculateTimeToWait(s) == 0))
                    .toList();
            execute(readySubscriptions);
            long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();

            readySubscriptions.forEach( s -> {
                long refreshTime = getExecutionTime(currentTimeMillis, s.refreshInterval());
                s.setLastRefresh(refreshTime);
            });
            return true;
        } catch (Exception t) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            t.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(baos, true));
            t = null;

            throw new ServiceException(baos.toString("UTF-8"));
        }
    }

    long getExecutionTime(long currentTimeMillis, long updateInterval) {
        long numberOfPeriods = (currentTimeMillis - startTime) / updateInterval;

        return startTime + (numberOfPeriods * updateInterval);
    }

    protected void asynchronouslyExecute(Callable<Void> job) {
        future(job, TypedActor.dispatcher());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there are a few things I don't like about this class.

Probably the biggest is that you're violating the `SRP`. That one type defines a `Service`, a `Publisher`, and a `Subscriber`.

Service classes should not extend `Service`. There should be one class that handles all the service-specific functionality, and it accepts some interface defining the service to be run. Conceptually, it should work exactly like `Thread`/`Executor` and `Runnable`, but presumably with more configuration options available. As it stands, it's very hard on casual inspection to see what is `Service`-specific and what is `Publisher`/`Subscriber` specific. It would also better if the `Subscriber` was its own top-level class.

It is very nonstandard for an `Impl` class to be abstract.

It looks like the extensibility of `PublisherImpl` has been poorly thought out. Some methods that look like they should be final aren't. There's no documentation to explain the intended use. Are you sure that you don't want a final `PublisherImpl` class which can accept `PublisherListener`s?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback much appreciated! The biggest issue which was so obvious (in hindsight) and the root of my discomfort with the class is the SRP voliolation. I think a lot of the other issues stem from this.

Comment: @munyengm No problem. Good luck going forward!